# How to make fields invisible for stock manager in odoo10

Tags: odoo-10

I want to invisible particular fields to stock manager and visible for stock user and Main Administrator(one of the stock manager).

for example:

```
<field name ="name_ids" groups="!group_stock_manager,group_stock_user"/>
```

It works but this field is not visible to the main administrator.

how I make visible this field to main administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `group_stock_manager` inherits from `group_stock_user`so you cannot restrict the first while allowing access to the second group. To solve it you may need to use other group different from `group_stock_user` to be able to isolate the permissions for `group_stock_manager` that will not be inherited from `group_stock_user`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But how do I isolate permissions with the use of other group? can you explain me.

Comment: I mean that you could replace your usage of the group `group_stock_user` with another existing group or just create a new one. The idea is to use a group that you could be sure that it's not inherited by `group_stock_manager`

Answer (score 0):

Like Axel was saying you need to isolate the permissions.  What you would need to do in your security definitions define the access rights to the field and use base.group_user.

Then create a new security group xml for people who can see and edit the field.